# How to calculate height and width of inner browser without including browser menu bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to calculate height and width of inner body of browser including browser scroll bar but without including browser menu toolbars using jquery.
After calculating height and width i want to set some header, body and footer. Also when I re size(expand and minimize) outside and inside scroll  appears which keeps my header, body, and footer fixed.

So what do I have to do in order to make it work cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to manually position your header and footer based on the size of the window.  Why not use CSS to just `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` to let the browser position it for you?

This will position header and footer at top and bottom of your document.

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Or, this will position at top and bottom of the window:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I will check it and get back to you.